# Finding the domain and range of a really large function

Tags: calculus

We can find out quickly the domain and range of simple functions like this:

$$f(x) = {x^2 + 1\over x^2 - 1}$$

However, what about those functions which are not so easy to calculate for the domain and range? For example, take a look at this rather extreme sample:

$$f(x) = {3x^{57} - 51x^{53} + 13x ^ {43} + 11x ^ {61} + x ^ {33}\over x^{23} - 13x^{67} + 12x ^ {33} - 19x^{19} - 23x^{59} + 17x^{91}}$$

How does one begin to calculate for the domain and range of this behemoth? Is there a universal procedure to calculate domains and ranges that apply from the very small, trivial function to very large ones?

Comment: This study requires the computation of roots of high degree polynomials, which is in general intractable.

Comment: Did you just make that up as an example, or is that one you actually face?

Comment: At least for rational functions $p(x) / q(x)$ there is a general procedure, but this doesn't mean that we can write the domain and range in a nice way, for the reason Yves mentions.

Comment: Well, the domain is all real numbers that are not roots of the polynomial in the denominator.  Is there any reason why anything more *needs* to be said?

Comment: The denominator has at least a root and quite likely it isn't also a root of the numerator. If this is the case, then the range is $\mathbb{R}$. The domain is $\mathbb{R}$ except the roots of the denominator. Note that verifying whether two polynomials have common roots can be done without computing them (using the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant)), but you need to compute a $152\times152$ determinant in this case.

Comment: Note that you can factor out $x^{19}$ from both numerator and denominator.

Comment: You can find the gcd of polynomials using the Euclidean algorithm, no $152 \times 152$ determinant needed.  In this case the gcd is $x^{19}$.  The denominator has two real roots besides $0$, and they are not roots of the numerator.